HTML banner not correctly aligning towards the top of the page
The code will always keep the div just under the top of the page, while not effecting the actual top. The div is the first of the page.
(IDE: VS Code, Debug browser: MS Edge)
What I tried:

Adding  tags: Didn't change anything
Removing margin + padding: Made it a null in the browser, still didn't change anything
Translate/transform: Ruins crossplatform compatibility



html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#Banner {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

#Image1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

#Projects button {
    display: none;
}

h1, p, #BannerText {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
<div id="Banner">
  <header>
    <h4 id="BannerText">FIRST PROJECT WILL BE COMING SOON</h4>
  </header>
</div>
<div id="Main">
  <h1>AU Programs</h1>
  <p>Hey! I'm an amateur programmer who loves to create and share projects.</p>
</div>




It is the same problem, but it happened for different reasons, --> this is the definition of duplicate: the same problem

It’s the default margin on your <h4> element which is causing that space at the top. Just set the margin on that element to zero. Learn more about the CSS box model and how margins work.


html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

header h4 {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
<header>
  <h4>First project will be coming soon</h4>
</header>
<main>
  <h1>AU Programs</h1>
  <p>Hey! I'm an amateur programmer who loves to create and share projects.</p>
</main>




if the problem is solved, then mark the answer, it will help others and also to avoid duplicate questions.

Just did, cheers!
